# C# to Python Cipher Text Differs When Plain Text Character Count > 16

Tags: python, c#, encryption, cryptography

I want to convert a c# code to python like this question: [Python to C# AES CBC PKCS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747042/python-to-c-sharp-aes-cbc-pkcs7#comment114888934_6772169)

When plain text's character count < 16, I give the same result both of this codes. (24 character)

But when plain text's character count >= 16, C# code returns result that has 44 characters and python returns result that has 24 characters. This are same characters but python is missing.
For example: c# result is `jfgdohpE8zrgls3Mpi8B+t/nGbzK1iEA3l1rJ0G8sFU=`,
python result is
`jfgdohpE8zrgls3Mpi8B+g==`
Why? ( I use Python3 and PKCS7 library for padding)

Comment: None of the two codes compile/run. The Python code lacks the definition for `PKCS7Encoder`. Also missing for both codes are _complete_ samples to reproduce the problem (ciphertext without plaintext and key don't help much). Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can u look at it now? I made some edits. @Topaco

Comment: The C# code still doesn't compile (`array` is not defined). Currently you are using a 32 byte key with 0 values (`array_bbb`). `array_bbb_2` is not used at all. No idea what you want to achieve.

Comment: During the first copy operation you copy the bytes 0-15 (`array_bbb_2`) to 0-15 (`array_bbb`). In the second copy operation you copy 0-15 (`array_bbb_2`) to 15-30 (`array_bbb`). Thereby the last byte of the first copy operation is overwritten. Is this really how it should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the line

```
AES_KEY = bytearray(bbb, 'utf-8')
```

must be removed in the Python code to derive the same key as in the C# code.

Then the problem you describe can be reproduced: The C# code returns e.g. for the base64 encoded IV `J223ULe3Xf6PX1KfNVmEiw==` and the plaintext and key posted by you the following ciphertext:

```
O5EBcIB987RNfZ41RbvRThmlEyP2RxkDCuGWQiajkDY=
```

while the Python code generates this ciphertext:

```
O5EBcIB987RNfZ41RbvRTg==
```

The reason is an already known bug in *pypkcs7* ([issue #1](https://github.com/jeppeter/pypkcs7/issues/1)) which makes this package practically unusable, because the padding generally does not comply with the PKCS7 definition anymore (specifically if the plaintext before padding has a length that is an integer multiple of the block size (16 bytes for AES)).

So you need a different PKCS7 implementation. Fortunately *PyCryptodome* provides a [padding module](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-padding-module) (not available in legacy *PyCrypto*). With the following change

```
#from pkcs7 import PKCS7Encoder
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
...
#encoder = PKCS7Encoder()
#padded_text = encoder.encode(secret_text)    
padded_text = pad(secret_text.encode('utf8'), 16).decode('utf8')
```

the same ciphertext is generated as by the C# code (by the way, the decoding can actually be omitted, because the encryption process encodes the ciphertext again; I have kept this only with regard to a comparison with the old implementation).

As a side note, the key can be more easily derived with:

```
hash = hashlib.sha256(bbb.encode('utf8')).digest() 
AES_KEY = hash[:15] + hash[:16] + b"\0"
```